# APEX 19.2 error when removing the workspace

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-19.2

I have a problem deleting a workspace in APEX 19.2. From the graphical interface or from SQL, it returns this error:
*Error removing workspace.
ORA-04091: table APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_FEEDBACK is mutating, trigger/function may not see it ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_ISSUES_AD", line 2 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_ISSUES_AD'*

The PL / SQL code:

```
BEGIN
   APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN.REMOVE_WORKSPACE('DOGO_PRO','N','N');
END;
```

The workspace I am trying to delete is called "DOG_PRO", in the APEX interface, it stays in this state:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItuSX.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7RNC.jpg)

How can I delete the workspace?
I have created new workspaces and they are removed without problems but this workspace gives me that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same error today with APEX 19.2.

I got it working by disabling the trigger `WWV_FLOW_ISSUES_AD` on the table `APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_ISSUES_AD` as user **SYS**. Then I was able to delete the workspace and re-enabled the trigger.

As I don't use the *Feedback Option* in APEX the table `APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_FEEDBACK` is empty and the trigger doesn't need to update any rows.

To disable the trigger use the following command:

```
alter trigger APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_ISSUES_AD disable;
```

Now you should be able to delete the workspace in Instance Admin or SQL/Plus.

To re-enable the trigger use the following command:

```
alter trigger APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_ISSUES_AD enable;
```